# What will CD spectroscopy show when L- and D- forms of proteins are mixed?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, biophysics, organic-chemistry, spectroscopy

What will happen if equimolar concentration of L- and D- forms of proteins are mixed and we take the circular dichroism reading? Will the positive and negative ellipticity cancel each other out or will there be positive and negative ellipticity of identical magnitude?

Comment: I’d be interested to know how you would obtain the D-form of a protein. I presume this is a hypothetical theoretical question. You might consider this clear in the question. As it has no biological significance it doesn't really belong here. It might be better on SE Chemistry, where you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Interesting that my answer was blocked. It gave the shortest and most precise answer possible to the question. (L and D forms are mirror images and the signal from each cancel out.) That is literally what happens! And the question contain the explanation already!